# Error when trying to include AudioStream.h from aws

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services

When I try to follow the example from
[this aws real time streaming example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/real-time-streaming-transcription-with-the-aws-c-sdk/)

why do i get the following error

```
/usr/local/include/aws/transcribestreaming/model/AudioStream.h:47:36: error: calling 'Jsonize' with incomplete return type 'Aws::Utils::Json::JsonValue'
       msg.WriteEventPayload(value.Jsonize().View().WriteCompact());
                             ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/aws/transcribestreaming/model/ConfigurationEvent.h:40:68: note: 'Jsonize' declared here
    AWS_TRANSCRIBESTREAMINGSERVICE_API Aws::Utils::Json::JsonValue Jsonize() const;
                                                                   ^
/usr/local/include/aws/transcribestreaming/model/PostCallAnalyticsSettings.h:18:9: note: forward declaration of 'Aws::Utils::Json::JsonValue'
  class JsonValue;
        ^
In file included from audiopa.cpp:4:
/usr/local/include/aws/transcribestreaming/model/AudioStream.h:47:45: error: member access into incomplete type 'Aws::Utils::Json::JsonValue'
       msg.WriteEventPayload(value.Jsonize().View().WriteCompact());
                                            ^
/usr/local/include/aws/transcribestreaming/model/PostCallAnalyticsSettings.h:18:9: note: forward declaration of 'Aws::Utils::Json::JsonValue'
  class JsonValue;
```

I'm really at a loss why this would happen since I'm just following what the example given and this problem happens even when I only have

```
#include <aws/transcribestreaming/model/AudioStream.h>
```

Comment: Q: Does the sample app from AWS (the one in your link) compile successfully?  Q: Did you include the required headers BEFORE "AudioStream.h" (e.g. "core/AwsS.h", "AWSVector.h", etdc)?  Q: Which C++ compiler/compiler version are you using (and does it support C++11 and higher)?

Comment: @pauIsm4  im using clang 14.0 which should support C++11 and also included the other two headers, i basically copied exactly what he did in the link except i fixed a bug following [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/issues/1432) and according to the issue on github the program should compile fine.

Comment: If their example doesn't compile, better to open a new issue on their Github repo.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code in the Github repo, instead of the blog code.
https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/cpp/example_code/transcribe

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).